# how to run Wamp server on a different port on localhost?

Tags: iis, localhost, wamp

how to run `WAMP` server on a different port on`localhost`?

I am already running `IIS` on `localhost:80` and I want to run WAMP server as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up WAMP settings file "http.conf" with a notepad. It's usually located in:

```
C:\wamp\Apache2\conf\
```

Then press CTRL + F to bring up find prompt, type "80" and hit enter. You should now see the line for setting the port. Change it to whatever you like (for example 8888), save the file and restart the web server.

Now you can access your Apache server with "localhost:8888".

Answer (score 2):

In version 2.2 of WAMP I found the config file under `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\httpd.conf`.

Also, I had to change line 46 to:

```
Listen 80
```

and line 171 to:

```
ServerName localhost:80
```